# Не работают border, background и другие теги

Tags: html, scss, background, border

Подгонял по размеру h1 и h2б а как решил добавить фон то не получилось, решил посмотреть границы но и это не вышло

```css
//Обнуление 
@import 'zerostyle.scss';
// div{ 
//  border: 1px solid #000; 
// } 
body {
  background: #000;
}

.block {
  background: #000;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 1190px;
  height: 1503px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  .Ellipse-1-copy {
    background: #000;
    width: 1190px;
    height: 1064px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  }
  .block2 {
    background: #000;
    width: 1190px;
    height: 1457px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  }
}

.Ellipse-1-copy {
  .title {
    width: 67px;
    height: 10px;
    padding: 47px 202px 0px 147px;
    margin: 0 392px 42px 382px;
    opacity: 0.6;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-stretch: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    line-height: 2.86;
    letter-spacing: 2.8px;
    text-align: center;
    color: rgba(39, 61, 70, 0.6);
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }
  .subtitle {
    display: block;
    width: 724px;
    height: 75px;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 206px;
    font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
    font-size: 36px;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-stretch: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    line-height: 1.39;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    text-align: center;
    color: #273d46;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UFT-8" />
  <title>SASS 1</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="block">
    <div class="block2">
      <div class="Ellipse-1-copy">
        <h1 class="title">Travel</h1>
        <h2 class="subtitle">Donec sed odio dui. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum.</h2>
        <!-- <div class="img">
                  <img src="../sass — practice/img/light-man copy.png" alt="#">
                </div> -->
        <!-- <div class="paragraphs">
                  <p class="paragraph_1">
                    Donec aredsed odio dui. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros. Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla.
                  </p>-->
      </div>
      <!-- <p class="paragraph_2">
                    Aenean eu leo quam. Pellentesque ornare sem lacinia quam venenatis vestibulum. Aenean eu leo quam. Pellentesque ornare sem lacinia quam venenatis vestibulum.
                  </p> -->
      <!-- </div>
              <ul class="list">
                <li>Put on this page information about your product</li>
                <li>A detailed description of your product</li>
                <li>Tell us about the advantages and merits</li>
                <li>Associate the page with the payment system</li>
              </ul>
              <button class="button">Full story</button>  -->
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Вы пытаетесь черные бордеры и черный фон на черном же фоне увидеть? Если у `body` фон `#000`, то имело бы смысл бордерам и фону заголовка назначить другой цвет...

Comment: так и фон черный не работает, страница белая

Comment: А вы уверены, что ваш `scss` компилируется в `css`?

Comment: Сконвертируйте Ваш SCSS в CSS и добавьте здесь в сниппет, все прекрасно работает.

Comment: Я бы настоятельно рекомендовал изучить сначала HTML. CSS. JS, а уже потом пробовать разбираться в препроцессорах.

Comment: запихнул в сниппет правкой, вроде scss и не должен сам по себе работать в браузере... но фоны всё равно работают. ляпота :3

Comment: @puffleeck, именно такой код со сниппета будет работать, [потому что вот](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_nesting/Using_CSS_nesting)

Comment: @De.Minov, поддержку которого буквально вчера видел здесь: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Nesting_selector к слову, у меня FF 91 esr, так что...)))